# Cannot read property 'equals' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm getting the following error when I try to update a post in my node/express app. I'm using mongoDB as well.

```
Cannot read property 'equals' of undefined
at eval (eval at compile 
(/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:549:12), 
<anonymous>:78:42)
at returnedFn 
(/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:580:17)
at tryHandleCache 
(/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:223:34)
at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] 
(/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:437:10)
```

Here is where the error is popping up

```
<% if(currentUser && 
bodhi.author.id.equals(currentUser._id) || currentUser && 
currentUser.isAdmin === true){ %>
```

Could this be a problem with the node/npm versions that I'm running?

I'm using node -v
v10.9.0 and npm -v
6.4.1

I have similar functionality working on an app that uses
v10.5.0 and npm -v
6.2.0

Here is my model:

```
    var mongoose = require("mongoose");
    var bodhiSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    donation: String,
    BTCaddress: String,
    image: String,
    imageId: String,
    description: String,
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
     author: {
     id: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User"
    },
    username: String
    },
    comments: [
    {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Comment"
    }
    ]
    });

    module.exports = mongoose.model("Bodhi", bodhiSchema);
```

Here is the block where the error is pointing to:

```
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row"> 
            <div class="thumbnail">
               <img class="img-responsive" src="<%= bodhi.image %>">
            <div class="caption-full">
               <h4>suggested donation <%= bodhi.donation %>/BTC<h4> 
               <hr>
               <h5><a><%=bodhi.name%></a></h5>
               <p><%= bodhi.description %></p>
               <p>
                  <em>Submitted by: <%= bodhi.author.username %>, <%= 
                moment(bodhi.createdAt).fromNow() %></em>
              </p>
               <% if(currentUser && 
              bodhi.author.id.equals(currentUser._id) || currentUser 
              && currentUser.isAdmin === true){ %>
                    <a class="btn btn-xs btn-warning" 
              href="/bodhis/<%=bodhi._id %>/edit">Edit</a>
                    <form class="delete-form" 
              action="/bodhis/<%=bodhi._id %>?_method=DELETE" 
              method="POST"
                          onsubmit="return confirm('Are You Sure You 
              Want To Delete This Bodhi?');">
                        <button class="btn btn-xs btn- 
              danger">Delete</button>
                    </form>
                <% }%>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
```

Here is my app.js file:

```
    var dotenv     = require('dotenv').config(),
        express    = require("express"),
        app        = express(),
        bodyParser = require("body-parser"), 
        mongoose   = require("mongoose"),
        flash      = require("connect-flash"),
        passport   = require("passport"),
        cookieParser = require("cookie-parser"),
        LocalStrategy = require("passport-local"),
        methodOverride = require("method-override"),
        Bodhi      = require("./models/bodhi"),
        Comment    = require("./models/comment"),
        User       = require("./models/user"),
        session = require("express-session"),
        moment = require('moment'),
        seedDB     = require("./seeds"),


    //requiring routes
    commentRoutes = require("./routes/comments"),
    bodhiRoutes   = require("./routes/bodhis"),
    indexRoutes   = require("./routes/index"),
    contactRoutes = require("./routes/contact");

    console.log(process.env.DATABASEURL);
    var url = process.env.DATABASEURL || 
    "mongodb://localhost/bodhishare";
    mongoose.connect(url);




    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
    app.set("view engine", "ejs");
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
    app.use(methodOverride("_method"));
    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.use(session({secret: process.env.secret}));
    app.use(flash());
    //seedDB(); //uncomment this line to seed the database

    app.locals.moment = require("moment");
    //passport config
    app.use(require("express-session")({
      secret: process.env.secret,
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: false
    }));

    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
    passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
    passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
    passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

    app.use(function(req, res, next){
      res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
      res.locals.error = req.flash("error");
      res.locals.success = req.flash("success");
      next();
    });

    app.use("/", indexRoutes);
    app.use("/bodhis", bodhiRoutes);
    app.use("/bodhis/:id/comments", commentRoutes);
    app.use("/contact", contactRoutes);



    app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP ,function(){
      console.log("The bodhishare server has started!");
    });
```

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's impossible to know where that `bodhi.author` is coming from.

Comment: Have you tried changing node version to v10.5.0 and npm -v 6.2.0? as you are saying it's working in this version. If yes do you still see the error? What is bodhi? Any sample data of the same

Comment: @Fcmam5 - I added the code that I think may be relevant above.

Comment: @Think-Twice - I tried changing the versions of both Node and npm to 10.5.0 & 6.2.0 respectively, and I'm still getting the error.

Comment: error is not of `node.js` or `npm` version. Check are you sending to `ejs` page on `res.render('index', {currentUser})` does your `currentUser` have `isAdmin` property.  try to check `currentUser` value and would recommend to change condition to `<% if(currentUser && 
              bodhi.author.id.equals(currentUser._id) || currentUser 
              && currentUser.isAdmin){ %>` If `isAdmin` will be present and have any value any one value of these `null, undefined, 0, false, NaN, ''` then condition will be `false`.

Comment: @NAVIN Thanks for the suggestion on the syntax issue. I changed it as you suggested. I'm still getting the error above though. The template of the div associated with the post route is working, but without any of the ejs content. Could it be a problem with my mongoose model?

Comment: resolved: typo in the middleware. Thanks guys